# Reference request: Cartier operator paper

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Feel free to delete this post if it is inappropriate.

Is there anyway one could access the paper by [[3] of Cartier](http://www.ihes.fr/%7Ecartier/REFERENCES/publications.html)?

```
Une nouvelle opération sur les formes différentielles. C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 244 (1957), 426-428.
```

I have been searching for quite a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available freely online from the French National Library [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31965/f426.item) (direct link). Back issues of the *Comptes Rendus* from 1835 through 1965 are available at the same location - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comptes_rendus_de_l%27Acad%C3%A9mie_des_Sciences#Online_open_archives) notes that all issues through 1996 are available freely online through the French national library, with links to the appropriate section of the website depending on the time period. Starting in 1997, the journal was published commercially by Elsevier - articles from 1997 to present will require different tactics.